# how to copy files without breaking utf8 filenames in ubuntu 8.04?

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, cp, unicode

I have a very old PC which is unable to run pretty much anything. It previously used Windows 7, but now everything I try just makes it reboot.

I, finally, managed to get access to it by running Ubuntu 8.04 Live CD on it.

Now I want to pull some files out of it to a network drive

I mounted my samba share in `/mnt/SB` and my disk is `/dev/sda3` which I mounted on `/mnt/sda3`

Now I tried to copy the files using the following commands

`rsync -rhv /mnt/sda3/* /mnt/SB/`

`cp -ra /mnt/sda3/* /mnt/SB/`

But both of them break the filenames which contain Greek Characters.

Is there a way to preserve the characters?

Any help is appreciated.

all `locale` output shows

`en_US.UTF-8`

I can't copy paste unfortunately.

Comment: I decided to go with `scp` which doesn't seem to be affected by this problem but I'd still like to know how to not be affected by this issue when using `rsync` or `cp`

Comment: I'm sorry, but Ubuntu 8.04 is 12 years old, and I think the desktop version passed end of life 9 years ago. You cannot expect, that we remember it well enough to help you.

Comment: Please update question to tell us: What filesystem are you copying from (If MS-Windows-7 then NTFS, or FAT)? NTFS and FAT don't use utf-8.

Comment: The mounted filesystem is NTFS

Comment: @sudodus unfortunately I tried everything < 14.04 to make it boot and the first one that actually worked was 8.04 so I'm stuck there. It was a last attempt to post here

Answer (score -1):

It's not `cp` or `rsync` that have trouble dealing with filenames, it's **file globbing** that is causing the issue. Even files with spaces in them will fail to copy when you say `cp -ra /mnt/sda3/* /mnt/SB/`.

Instead, try the following command:

```
cp -ra /mnt/sda3/ /mnt/SB/
```

Comment: Globbing does not split mindlessly. In this case spaces in filenames should not be an issue, even in 2008.

Comment: same result like this. I tried copying the whole directory like `cp -ra /mnt/sda3 /mnt/` and it was problematic too so I don't think it has to do with globbing. The files are not being split either. THey're being created normally but with broken filenames.